# How to get the user selection from startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Open file using..."), APP_PICKED);?

Tags: android, android-intent, selection

Is there any way to get programmatically the user selection after

```
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Open file using..."), APP_PICKED);
```

or

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Open file using..."));
```

I do not want to start the selected application - I only want to know which one is it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you cannot find out what the user chose.

You can, however, use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to make your own chooser.