# Callback from chooser

Tags: android, android-intent

I just started implementing a share functionality but was wondering if its possible to tell how my content was shared (facebook/twitter/text/etc) without writing my own implementation of chooser. My initial guess was to use startActivityForResult when launching the chooser but haven't managed to figure out which requestcode to use.

```
public void share(String subject,String text) {
 final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, getString(R.string.share)));
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the user selection from startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(fileIntent, "Open file using..."), APP_PICKED);?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417019/how-to-get-the-user-selection-from-startactivityforresultintent-createchooserf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My initial guess was to use startActivityForResult when launching the chooser but haven't managed to figure out which requestcode to use.

That will not work reliably. ~99% of activities are not set up to work with `startActivityForResult`.

> I just started implementing a share functionality but was wondering if its possible to tell how my content was shared (facebook/twitter/text/etc) without writing my own implementation of chooser

Sorry, you will need to write your own chooser for this.