# onActivityResult() method always returns 0 - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onactivityresult

In my android application, I am providing image sharing functionality. Now, i want that After completing image sharing functionality from my current activity, user should be redirected to HomeActivity. For that i have user `onActivityResult()` method in my code. But the problem is that, it always returns 0,hence it doesn't start HomeActivity. I went though many posts but couldn't get solution. Please help me to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Code of CurrentActivity:

```
     @Override
            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                try {
                    switch (requestCode) {
                    case SHARE_PIC:

//The following condition is not satisfied while debugging.
                        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            GlobalClass.finalPath = null;
                            FaceFrameActivity_temp.this.finish();
                            Intent in = new Intent(FaceFrameActivity_temp.this,
                                    HomeActivity.class);
                            in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(in);
                            GlobalClass.finalPath = null;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }


           //Button click will handle sharing functionality.
           btnOk.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {

                                if (txtFile.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {

                                    if (GlobalClass.finalPath == null) {
                                        finalBitmap = FaceFrameActivity_temp.this.frmView
                                                .getDrawingCache();
                                        SaveToSDcard(finalBitmap, txtFile.getText()
                                                .toString());

                                    }


                                    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                                    share.setType("image/*");
                                    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri
                                            .fromFile(new File(GlobalClass.finalPath)));

                                    FaceFrameActivity_temp.this.startActivityForResult(
                                            Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"),
                                            SHARE_PIC); //SHARE_PIC = 3
                                }
                            }
                        });
```

From currentActivity, i have opened Intent for sharing image. When image sharing is completed and user returns to application, at that time i want to open Home activity.The problem is that, it doesn't execute my code of `onActivityResult()` of currentActivity.

Comment: try this way resultCode == RESULT_OK

Comment: have you debug your code ? which result code that you get in overrided onActivityResult() method ?

Comment: its not working.Still it returns 0.

Comment: Yes i already debugged my code,while debugging `resultCode` value is 0.

Answer (score 1):

you can set value from comeback to second activity to home activity.

like this

```
Intent result = new Intent();
     result.putExtra("ARTICLE", main_String);                   
     setResult(101, result);                    
     finish();
```

And set condition like this in home activity.

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

 switch(resultCode){

    case 101:
                  // your condition.....

         break;

    case 102:
                    // your condition.....
         break;

    case 103:
             // your condition.....
        break;
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
Start the Activity like below

```
  v.getContext().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"),
                                            SHARE_PIC);
```

Comment: here i am using it with dialog. So i wrote `dialog.getContext().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"),
                                            SHARE_PIC);` but throwing an error that `onActivityResult() is undefined for the type Context`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that startActivityForResult on an IntentChooser will work.
I will copy/past from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9982349/callback-from-chooser):

> That will not work reliably. ~99% of activities are not set up to work
>   with startActivityForResult.